# imagecreatefrompng returning data dump

Tags: php, png, imagecreatefrompng

I am trying to get a png image to display using imagecreatefrompng, but when I keep getting this: [image: What imagecreatefrompng returns]

Here is my code:

```
$img = 'stamp.png';
$img = imagecreatefrompng($img);
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($img);
imagedestroy($img);
```

Comment: Is this your ENTIRE code?

Comment: I have the standard <!doctype html> and <?php> code as well

Comment: Thats your problem, you dont embed image data into html do you, html is just text. Remove the html

Comment: If you are still confused, edit your question to show the complete php file, and i'll post an answer